# Emotion results from the cognitive APIs - face vs emotion

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

EDIT: Question is added on request from Azure Support.

Are the emotions results from the Face API (detect) the same as results returned from the Emotion API?

EDIT2: If you look at the results from the face API, then you can get the emotions from a picture and this is without making a request to the emotions API. I am wondering if it is the same results you get from the Face API as if you'd request the emotions API. The results from the Face API seem to be rounded.

Comment: Question is added by request from Azure support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide an answer:

> The Emotion API takes a facial expression in an image as an input, and returns the confidence across a set of emotions for each face in the image, as well as bounding box for the face, using the Face API.

Source is [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/emotion/)